# how to create custom periodic task in celery in django

Tags: django, celery, django-celery-beat

I want to create a shedular while a API was getting hit after that i have to create the
after that i have to stop the shedular in another api was get hitting

API1 --> trigger the celery cron for 3 min periodic task

API2 --> stop the celery periodic task how

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[django_celery_beat][1]

from django_celery_beat.models import PeriodicTask, IntervalSchedule

# executes every 10 seconds.
>>> schedule, created = IntervalSchedule.objects.get_or_create(
...     every=10,
...     period=IntervalSchedule.SECONDS,
... )

>>> PeriodicTask.objects.create(
...     interval=schedule,                  # we created this above.
...     name='Importing contacts',          # simply describes this periodic task.
...     task='proj.tasks.import_contacts',  # name of task.
... )
```

I use this package in my project, you can try this.